terraform error when integrating S3 website redirect with CloudFront
I am using the
aws_s3_bucket_website_configuration
resource to configure the S3 website redirect and when I reference that in the origin block of the aws_cloudfront_distribution resource  I get the following error:
Error: creating CloudFront Distribution: operation error CloudFront: CreateDistributionWithTags, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: 123456789, InvalidArgument: The parameter Origin DomainName does not refer to a valid S3 bucket.

Here is the complete code:
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "cf_s3_bucket" {
  bucket = var.cf_s3_bucket
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_website_configuration" "cf_s3_bucket" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.cf_s3_bucket.id

 redirect_all_requests_to {
  host_name = var.s3_redirect_destination
  protocol = "https"
  }
}

resource "aws_cloudfront_origin_access_control" "cf_oac" {
  name                              = "travel"
  description                       = "travel policy"
  origin_access_control_origin_type = "s3"
  signing_behavior                  = "always"
  signing_protocol                  = "sigv4"
}

resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "s3_distribution" {
  comment = var.cf_dist_comment
  aliases = var.alt_domain_names

  default_cache_behavior {
    allowed_methods  = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    cached_methods   = ["GET", "HEAD"]
    target_origin_id = local.s3_origin_id

    forwarded_values {
      query_string = false

      cookies {
        forward = "none"
      }
    }

    viewer_protocol_policy = "redirect-to-https"
  }

  default_root_object = "index.html"
  enabled             = true
  http_version        = "http2"
  is_ipv6_enabled     = false

   origin {
    connection_attempts      = 3
    connection_timeout       = 10
    domain_name              = aws_s3_bucket_website_configuration.cf_s3_bucket.website_endpoint
    origin_access_control_id = aws_cloudfront_origin_access_control.cf_oac.id
    origin_id                = local.s3_origin_id
  }

  price_class = "PriceClass_100"

  restrictions {
    geo_restriction {
      restriction_type = "none"
    }
  }

  viewer_certificate {
    acm_certificate_arn = var.acm_cert_arn
    minimum_protocol_version = "TLSv1.2_2021"
    ssl_support_method = "sni-only"
  }
}

If I change
domain_name
to
domain_name=aws_s3_bucket.cf_s3_bucket.bucket_regional_domain_name
then I do not get the error. However, when I look at the Origin in the CloudFront console I see this message
This S3 bucket has static web hosting enabled. If you plan to use this distribution as a website, we recommend using the S3 website endpoint rather than the bucket endpoint.
Therefore, I have the wrong Origin domain value in CloudFront which results in Access Denied in my browser and I have to manually change it in the CloudFront console in order for the redirect to work.
My question is can I use
domain_name = aws_s3_bucket_website_configuration.cf_s3_bucket.website_endpoint
and if not, how do I get the correct value for
domain_name
in the origin block?

Seems I got the same issue:  create failed: async create failed: failed to create the resource: [{0 creating CloudFront Distribution: operation error CloudFront: CreateDistributionWithTags, exceeded maximum number of attempts, 3, https response error StatusCode: 503, RequestID: b5b929c7-985f-4b62-9329-5ab1841f9411, api error ServiceUnavailable: CloudFront encountered an internal error. Please try again

Yes you can and should. But you have to configure it with the custom_origin_config and it needs to be http-only.
  origin {
    domain_name = aws_s3_bucket_website_configuration.cf_s3_bucket.website_endpoint
    origin_id   = local.s3_origin_id
    custom_origin_config {
      http_port              = "80"
      https_port             = "443"
      origin_protocol_policy = "http-only"
      origin_ssl_protocols   = ["TLSv1.2"]
    }
  }


Thanks for your response.  It has fixed my problem.  I need to get a better grasp on what the custom_origin_config is doing.
